# Saving Facebook access_token in NSUserDefaults on iOS

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults, token, access-token

iOS beginner here. I'm using the following code to save my facebook accessToken and expirationDate in NSUserDefaults:

```
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"225083222506272"];
    [facebook authorize:nil delegate:self];
    NSString *access=[facebook accessToken];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:access, @"accessToken",[facebook expirationDate], @"expirationDate",nil];
    [defaults registerDefaults:appDefaults];
```

And I'm trying to retrieve accessToken and expirationDate in a later call with:

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *access=[defaults valueForKey:@"accessToken"];
    NSDate *date=[defaults objectForKey:@"expirationDate"];
    [facebook fbDialogLogin:access expirationDate:date];
```

but access and date are null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: NSLog your access NSString. Is it returning a value?

Comment: why is it returning null? It should be returning a value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code here is not synchronous. It means it does not block after the call to `[facebook authorize:nil delegate:self];`. You should instead implement the `fbDidLogin` delegate method to be notified of when the user has actually logged in successfully. At that point, retrieve the access tokens and save them to user defaults.

Here's a partial sample:

```
- (void)userClickedFacebookLogin {
    [facebook authorize:nil delegate:self]; // delegate is self
}

// Delegate method that you should implement to get notified
// when user actualy logs in.
- (void)fbDidLogin {
    // now get the access token and save to user defaults
    NSString *access = [facebook accessToken];
    // ..
}
```

Also make sure that the class which has the above code implements the `FBSessionDelegate` protocol at minimum.

```
@interface MyClass <FBSessionDelegate> {

}

@end
```

Look at the [`DemoApp`](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample/DemoApp) sample and specifically the [`DemoAppViewController`](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/sample/DemoApp/Classes/DemoAppViewController.m) class from Facebook to get a better idea.

Comment: Thanks that saves it into NSUserDefaults. If I rerun the project, it will be from scratch and I'll have to login again, right?

Comment: not sure - I *think* Facebook may have cache the authorization status in the `Documents/` folder, but you can check.